# Moving a Div on Mouse Move

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jquery code that triggers the div to move on movement on a mouse wheel.

The code below works on mouse wheel movement.

What i am trying to implement is that i want the div to move when the mouse is moved to the left or right of the screen?

```
function scrollLeft() {
    var $left = Math.abs(Number($galleryList.css("margin-left").replace("px", "")))
    ;
    if ($left - itemWidth <= 0) {
        $galleryList.css({"margin-left": ""});
    }
    else {
        $galleryList.css({"margin-left": -1 * Number($left - itemWidth) + "px"});
    }
    $(document).trigger("mousemove");
}

function scrollRight() {
    var $left = Math.abs(Number($galleryList.css("margin-left").replace("px", "")))
    ;

    if ($galleryList.width() < itemWidth + $left + $window.width()) {
        $galleryList.css({"margin-left": -1 * Number($galleryList.width() - $window.width()) + "px"});
    }
    else {
        $galleryList.css({"margin-left": -1 * Number($left + itemWidth) + "px"});
    }
    $(document).trigger("mousemove");
}

$window.on("mousewheel", function (event) {
    if (stackedMode) {
        return true;
    }
    if (event.deltaY == 1) { // left
        scrollLeft();
    }
    else if (event.deltaY == -1) { // right
        scrollRight();
    }
    animating = true;
    setTimeout(function () {
        animating = false;
    }, 500);
})
```

Comment: Which part of it is causing you problems?

Comment: @EvanKnowles this code wors fine on Mouse wheel movement. I am trying to figure out how to make it move on mouse movement rather than using the mouse wheel

Comment: Write a `mousemove` handler.

Comment: @Barmar this is what i am not sure of how to go about

Comment: Doesn't [this](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) help you? Do you want the div to follow your mouse? Maybe simply modify the X position (if your div has an absolute position) depending on "event.pageX"?